# Change a root folder for a view in StarTeam

Tags: version-control, starteam

I'd like to change the "Root folder" for one of the existing views in StarTeam.
There's a possibility to change a working folder (via "View / Properties" dialog), but that's not the feature I need as it is done locally only.
Does anyone know how could I change it so that any user who switches to this view sees the new structure?

Comment: Can you specify what you see as the difference between the "root folder" and the "working folder"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a View you can set the Default Working Folder that will be shared initially for ALL users of that View within a Project or you can set an Alternate Working Folder that is specific to only YOUR local workstation.  The screen is under View->Properties:

[image: StarTeam View Properties Screen]

You can find additional information about this within the documentation: [Changing a View's Default and Alternate Working Folders](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.borland.stcpc.doc%2FSTARTEAM-9C615896-CHANGEDEFWORKFOLDER-TSK.html)